# Does the Grails undocumented method ifPageProperty actually work?

Tags: grails, sitemesh

I am setting a `pageProperty` in my view with a `content` tag, however, Grails 1.3.6 `ifPageProperty` is not detecting my sidebar `pageProperty`. Any thoughts?

layout.gsp

```
<g:ifPageProperty name="page.sidebar">
  <aside id="sidebar">
    <g:pageProperty name="page.sidebar" />
  </aside>
</g:ifPageProperty>
```

view.gsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Account Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <content tag="sidebar">
    <h4>Sidebar</h4>
    <p>Hola. This is a sidebar test!</p>
  </content>
  <h1>Content Heading</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

PS. If you're wondering where I am setting my layout, it's being set in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coworker scoured the Grails buglist and found out that Sitemesh's preprocess must be turned off.

```
// enable Sitemesh preprocessing of GSP pages
grails.views.gsp.sitemesh.preprocess = false
```

Comment: Hi, please report a bug in Grails Jira. I checked out the source code for ifPageProperty and there is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this as a workaround for the problem:

```
<g:if test="${g.pageProperty(name:'page.sidebar')?.length()}">
  <aside id="sidebar">
    <g:pageProperty name="page.sidebar" />
  </aside>
</g:if>
```

Comment: Ugh, but this is a sloppy for multiple decorators. I'll wait until Sitemesh and Grails hits.